# passing values from one page to another page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using html pages at front. I send information from html page to jquery for authentication to controller. Controller send back regarding information to jquery. How can i send this information to another html page. my script is written in separate js file. Please help how can i solve this. Thanks

Comment: Could maybe put it in `localStorage`, but really the server should handle this kind of thing.

Comment: Would you mind showing us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is small pieces of information you wish to send to to another page, you could use `querystring`

You can then use it by checking for them with javascript ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript))

If you don't know what a querystring is, it is the information you get in the form of:

```
www.website.com/somefolder/somepage?ID=124
```

where the part after the `?` is the `querystring`.

(NOTE: This is only useful for single page value passes, and not safe for sensitive information)

Answer (score 2):

I would use ajax to post the data to the server, and save the data in a session.